# Visual Studio Setup Project - one file in two locations

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, installation

What I want is make my setup project install same file in two different locations. When I try to do that, it adds that file again into my project which doubles the size of the .msi in the end. What can I do about this? Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding a file:

- Go to add Existing Item
- In the bottom left corner where it says Open drop the drop down box and select `Link file`
- click ok

This will then add the file as a link instead of copying the file to your project directory

More info [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306234)

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is to install the file at one place. Create a [Custom Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d9k65z2d(v=vs.100).aspx) that creates a copy of the file on the second place. Please take care that you remove that file as well at uninstall time.